# jQuery title flashing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a basic chat script and just having a slight hickup with the following code. Basically, I'm trying to make the page title "flash" similar to how facebook  does.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var title = $("title");

        var flash = setInterval(function(){
            $("#chatbox_2").toggleClass('notify');
            (title.text == 'blah') ? title.text("New message...") : title.text('blah');
        }, 900);
    });
</script>
```

If I `console.log(title.text());` it returns `blah`

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `title.text == 'blah'` to `title.text() == 'blah'`

Comment: I knew it was something so simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing parentheses after your invocation of `.text` in the ternary's conditional.

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to change the document title is `document.title = "New title";`

With that in mind, suitable JavaScript would be:

```
(function() {
    var toggle = false,
        chatbox = document.getElementById('chatbox_2'),
        flash = window.setInterval(function() {
            toggle = !toggle;
            chatbox.className = chatbox.className.replace(/(?:\bnotify\b\s?)?/,toggle ? 'notify ' : '');
            document.title = toggle ? "New message..." : "blah";
        },900);
})();
```